# Call code-behind method from .aspx site

Tags: asp.net, methods, code-behind

i want to call a method from a code-behind file.
I already read all threads/posts etc. but it don't work!

I tried to

- call Image1.DataBind(); Image1.ImageUrl="test.jpg"
- call OnDataBinding="methodname" and the correct method
- call ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(1) %> or <%= GetImage(1) %>

Here is some code snippet from my files.

**ASPX Site:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Abstimmung.aspx.cs" Inherits="Schulsprecher.Abstimmung" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
.
.
<form id="form1" runat="server">
.
.
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="300px" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(1) %>' />
```

**Code-Behind File**

```
protected string GetImage(string index)
{
    return "test.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Your image in in a DB? How are you streaming it back, can you show us your code, HttpHandler?

Comment: no my image is stored in a directory - I only save the path in the db and want to return a path (string) and set it to the ImageURL-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change it to normal html image tag, you can do this

```
<img ID="Image2" width="250" height="300" src='<%= GetImage("1") %>' />
```

Is it mandatory you should use `<asp:Image />`? I tried that with no success